# maven decypher dependency resolution

Tags: maven, dependencies, resolution

I'm trying to consume a component from our local repo. They have a convention of using version-ranges for everything, so I'm depending on, say, [10.4.1,10.4.2). They do this to define their parent POMs and all the other components they produce. It seems a bit of a tangle, but I guess it works for them. However, it's not working for me.

I get a dependency resolution error that suggests that Maven has selected not-the-latest version of the component I'm consuming, which then is somehow depending on an old version of another component (e.g. 10.2.4) which is no longer in the repo. A couple of hours of going through POMs has not moved me anywhere. Maven's debug output only seems to report what it's downloading, not what it's doing with the files once they are downloaded.

I've looked through the Maven source, and I don't see much debug logging.

I'm not expecting anyone to know how to fix this particular problem. What I'd like to know is how can you go about figuring out what Maven is doing? Why did it choose the versions it did? What files did it use? Etc.

Thanks very much to anyone who can help.

Comment: Simple recommendation I can give. Never use versions ranges. This makes your build non reproducible...Furthermore do people delete release versions from your repository? If yes than they didn't understand the impact...Apart from that without the paricular pom file and the content of your repositories it is impossible to follow the problem...

Comment: I agree totally. It's not my choice. I'm sure they delete older versions. I just need to figure out what's happening.